# Heap space error when using large table in iText 7 with vert.x framework

Tags: java, itext7

I have developed a PDF Generating app using iText and vert.x framework. The generated pdf contains tables and to ensure it can generate tables with a large number of raws, I enable large table when initialising the tables (`new Table(float[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, true)`) and flush the table using `table.flush()` command.

The application worked perfectly on a small amount of data but when I tried to create pdf with a large number of data (18,000 raws) it gives heap space error. then I set the max heap size to 2GB but still, an error occurred. Then I took the heap dump of the application and found out the main reason for heap space error is, `com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfIndirectReference` have larger retained heap and it contains `com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfIndirectReference`. For more understanding check the attached screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of heap analyser]

And here is the code example for each line of the table (repeatedly execute until all the data is finished)

```
Cell cell1 = createCcCell(createCcPara(a[0]).setFontSize(6));
    Cell cell2 = createCcCell(createCcPara(a[2]).setFontSize(6));
    Cell cell3 = createCcCell(createCcPara(a[7]).setFontSize(6));
    Cell cell4 = createCcCell(createCcPara(a[6]).setFontSize(6));
    Cell cell5 = createCcCell(createCcPara(a[5].split("T")[0] +" "+a[5].split("T")[1].substring(0,8)).setFontSize(6));
    Cell cell6 = createCcCell(createCcPara(a[1]).setFontSize(6));
    Cell cell7 = createCcCell(createCcPara(a[3]).setFontSize(6));
    Cell cell8 = createCcCell(createCcPara(a[4]).setFontSize(6));
    Cell cell9 = createCcCell(createCcPara(a[8]).setFontSize(6));
    Cell cell10 = createCcCell(createCcPara(a[9]).setFontSize(6));

    table
      .addCell(cell1)
      .addCell(cell2)
      .addCell(cell3)
      .addCell(cell4)
      .addCell(cell5)
      .addCell(cell6)
      .addCell(cell7)
      .addCell(cell9)
      .addCell(cell10)
      .addCell(cell8);
```

`createCcCell` method:

```
private Cell createCcCell (Paragraph content) {
    return new Cell()
      .setBorder(new SolidBorder(ColorConstants.BLACK, 0.5f))
      .setPaddingLeft(2)
      .setPaddingTop(0)
      .setPaddingBottom(0)
      .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT)
      .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
      .add(content);
  }
```

`createCcPara` method:

```
private Paragraph createCcPara (String content) {
    Paragraph newPara = new Paragraph(content)
      .setFontSize(5)
      .setFontColor(new DeviceCmyk(0, 0, 0, 100));

    try {
      newPara.setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA));
    } catch (IOException e){
      logger.warn("Font setting failed for cc table due to "+e.getMessage());
    }

    return newPara;
  }
```

Can anyone explain what is the reason for this heap issue and is there any way to fix this.

Comment: Please share enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: what does the issue have to do with vertx?

Comment: @injecteer project was implemented using vertex, So it may not be directly associated with the problem. But its asynchronous behaviour may be, That's why I mentioned it.

Comment: I see nothing in your code about asyncronous behaviour. I'm also 99% sure, that the same behaviour you would get in any JVM process be it in a container or not...

Comment: @injecteer I removed the vert.x tag due to your information. Thanks.

Comment: *"And here is the code example for each line of the table (repeatedly execute until all the data is finished)"* - I don't see a `flush` call near there.

Comment: @mkl I call the flush after every five iterations (inside for loop) I did not writer entire loop because it makes question larger. Even I tried to flush the table after adding every raw. But that also did not work.

Comment: *"I call the flush after every five iterations (inside for loop)"* - ah, that information was missing, doing so should normally suffice. In that case I have no specific idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve this issue in several ways. But I could not found a way to decrease heap size by optimising data structures or there were no iText related solutions found to fix the issue.

Then I found an architectural solution for the issue. Instead of creating entire pdf at once, I divide data into several parts and create separate PDFs for each chunk of data. and finally, merge those pdf using iText `PdfMerger`.

That gave me another advantage. since I worked with vert.x I use a method that returns vert.x `Future` for creating pdf parts and using `CompositeFuture.all()` method to execute all those Futures parallel and that makes my app more faster.

Comment: You also have many repeated style attributes for every cell. I would try one version without all font and other settings.

Comment: I'll try that too. Thanks for the idea.